# Seeing if input matches array if not alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, matching

```
var tagAllowed = true;
var allowedTags =["Person","People","Dance","Word"];
 if(tagAllowed === true) {
  for(var i=0;i<allowedTags.length;i++){
             var aTags = allowedTags[i];
     if(input.val().toLowerCase() === aTags.toLowerCase()) {
       tagged.append('<span unselectable="on" class="tagged '+colorize+'" title="Click To Delete">'+inputVal.trim()+'</span>');
       tagSize = $('.tagged').length;
       var ele = $('.tagged').last(),
       subtract = parseInt(ele.outerWidth(true),10);
       input.width(input.width() - subtract);
       tagged.width(tagged.width() + subtract);
       input.css('marginLeft','5px');
       input.val("");
       input.css('color','#000');
       } else {
                  errorMess.children('span').remove();
                  errorMess.prepend('<span>'+errorProcess+'<span>');
                  errorMess.slideDown();
       }
    }
```

The following code works in a way, if the input.val() does not match it will show the custom alert `errorMess` and well even if the word matches it still shows the custom alert. I am wondering if maybe I am doing something wrong in my conditional. As I don't need the custom alert to appear if the words match.

If any suggestions please post. I know this isn't the best example with just a code, but I hope all of you get what I am trying to say. I just don't want the custom alert to appear if the two words match together.

Comment: add a `break;` after your `input.css('color, '#000');` line. also, you should really change those last 3 lines to: `input.val("").css({marginLeft:'5px', color:'#000'});`. Making calls to .css() is slow, so it's better to do as much as you can in one call.

Comment: lol :D I completely overlooked that. It was just the start and I add the color change later. Thank you. I'll try it out now

Comment: ok so it worked for the first one and not the others. should I do return; break; ?

Comment: the reason you still get the error message is because it's failing the test on your input at some point. putting break after it finds one will stop it from showing an error the next time it runs through, when it fails. you probably want better logic in your code if you want it to behave more naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the if-statement inside the for-loop. The input value will never equal more than one of the tags in the array. You could use a for-loop to set a boolean. Then the if-statement could follow the for-loop.

```
boolean isAllowedTag = false;
for(var i=0;i<allowedTags.length;i++){
     var aTags = allowedTags[i];
     if(input.val().toLowerCase() === aTags.toLowerCase()) {
         isAllowedTag = true;
         break;
    }
}
if (isAllowedTag) {
      // ...
   } else {
        errorMess.children('span').remove();
        errorMess.prepend('<span>'+errorProcess+'<span>');
        errorMess.slideDown();
   }
}
```

Comment: this code works! I see what you have done here as well. As I have a view booleans in the code already and completely never even thought about it either! Thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

add a `break;` after your `input.css('color, '#000');` line. also, you should really change those last 3 lines to: `input.val("").css({marginLeft:'5px', color:'#000'});`. Making calls to .css() is slow, so it's better to do as much as you can in one call.